# Can items in PHP associative arrays not be accessed numerically (i.e. by index)?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to understand why, on my page with a query string, 
**the code:**

```
echo "Item count = " . count($_GET);
echo "First item = " . $_GET[0];
```

**Results in:**

> Item count = 3
>      First item =

Are PHP associative arrays distinct from numeric arrays, so that their items cannot be accessed by index?  Thanks-

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to rely on how `$_GET` may be sorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can not. When you subscript a value by its key/index, it must match exactly.

If you really wanted to use numeric keys, you could use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on `$_GET`, but you will lose all the information about the keys. You could also use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get the keys with numerical indexes.

Alternatively, as [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) mentions, you can [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) the internal pointer to get the first. You can also get the last with [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php). You can also pop or shift with [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) and [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php), both which will return the value once the array is modified.

Comment: You can use [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) to fetch the first value in an associative array

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the key of an array element is either an integer (must not be starting with 0) or an associative key, not both.

You can access the items either with a loop like this:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
}
```

Or get the values as an numerical array starting with key 0 with the `array_values()` function or get the first value with `reset()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
$keys = array_keys($_GET);

echo "First item = " . $_GET[$keys[0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it is not possible.

Try this:

`file.php?foo=bar`

`file.php` contents:

```
<?php

print_r($_GET);

?>
```

You get

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
)
```

If you want to access the element at 0, try `file.php?0=foobar`.

You can also use a `foreach` or `for` loop and simply break after the first element (or whatever element you happen to want to reach):

```
foreach($_GET as $value){
    echo($value);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope -- they are mapped by key value pairs. You can iterate the they KV pair into an indexed array though:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $getArray[] = $value;
}
```

You can now access the values by index within $getArray.

Answer (score 0):

As another weird workaround, you can access the very first element using:

```
 print $_GET[key($_GET)];
```

This utilizes the internal array pointer, like reset/end/current(), could be useful in an `each()` loop.