# Associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

I have two arrays:

```
 arr1([0]=>1400.20
      [1]=>1630.32
      [2]=>2531.30
      [3]=>9845.62)

 arr2([0]=>150
      [1]=>134
      [2]=>901
      [3]=>631)
```

and I have combined them as:

```
 arr3  ([150]=>1400.20
        [134]=>1630.32
        [901]=>2531.30
        [631]=>9845.62)
```

But I need to convert `arr3` to this form :

```
 arr4 ('150'=>1400.20,
       '134'=>1630.32,
       '901'=>2531.30,
       '631'=>9845.62)
```

Is there any way to convert `arr3` to this form?

I use two PHP program to create a graph by [phpMyGraph](http://phpmygraph.abisvmm.nl)
The first program takes information from the database and creates two arrays, `arr1`, `arr2`.The values in `arr1` will be the x-axis and the values in arr2 will be y-axis. After combining them

`$arr3 = array_combine($arr2, $arr1)`

I use 'serialize' to send `arr3` to the other program. But it doesn't show the graph and shows this message:

> exception 'Exception' with message 'Provide data is not an array.' in
>   blah/blah/phpMyGraph4.0.php:801 Stack trace: ....

I think maybe I need to use arr4 format as it is in the [exmple](http://phpmygraph.abisvmm.nl/index4.php)

Comment: can you please post your code where you combine these?

Comment: There's not *really* a difference considering PHP is weakly typed.

Comment: i'm wondering what's the difference

Comment: What does that mean? You need your keys to be strings?

Comment: It's already that way, try `echo $arr3['150'];`

Comment: can you please post your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are numeric and associative arrays in PHP two different things?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931206/are-numeric-and-associative-arrays-in-php-two-different-things)

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr3 = array();
foreach( $arr1 as $key => $value ){
    // arr1 [0]=>150
    // arr2 [0]=>1500
    // arr3[150] => 1500
    $arr3[$value] = $arr2[$key];
    
}
```

for avoid memory usage

```
  foreach( $arr1 as $key => $value ){
        // arr1 [0]=>150
        // arr2 [0]=>1500
        // arr2 [150] => 1500
        // delete arr2[0];
        $arr2[$value] = $arr2[$key];
        unset($arr2[$key]);
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $arr3 as &$key => &$value ){
    $key = '' . $key . '';
}
```

But as others have said, PHP has very weak type standards.