# Format JSON conditionally

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to **learn** PHP and am just trying to generate some JSON

This is the format I want it in.

```
{
    "Data": "Message was sent on 12-31-1999 12:00:00 am",
    "Sandbox": {
        "Sandboxed": true
    },
    "Errors": [{
        "Code": 5,
        "Message": "Message bounced back"
    }]
}
```

And I can do that with :

```
$message = "Message was sent on 12-31-1999 12:00:00 am";
$errorMsg = "Message bounced back";

$sandboxkey = array( "Sandboxed" => true );

$error = array( "Code" => 5, "Message" => $errorMsg );

$package = array(
    "Data" => $message,
    "Sandbox" => $sandboxkey,
    "Errors" => $error
);

return json_encode($package, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

But I want to only add the "Sandbox" key/value if a boolean is set.

```
$isSandbox = true;
$message = "Message was sent on 12-31-1999 12:00:00 am";
$errorMsg = "Message bounced back";
$error = array( "Code" => 5, "Message" => $errorMsg );
$package = array(
    "Data" => $message,
    "Errors" => $error
);
if ($isSandbox) {
    $sandboxkey = array( "Sandboxed" => true );
    array_push($package, $sandboxkey);
}
$error = array( "Code" => 5, "Message" => $errorMsg );
return json_encode($package, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

But that adds a "0" then the KVP.

```
{
    "Data": "Message was sent on 12-31-1999 12:00:00 am",
    "Errors": {
        "Code": 5,
        "Message": "Message bounced back"
    },
    "0": {
        "Sandboxed": true
    }
}
```

**Additionally, I want the Errors to be listed in an array like:**

```
"Errors": [{
        "Code": 5,
        "Message": "Message bounced back"
    },
            {
        "Code": 4,
        "Message": "Message is old"
    }  ]
```

**I have tried multiple combinations of array push, and JSON_FORCE_OBJECT but I just can't seem to get it exactly how I want. Can anyone help?**

Comment: `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT ` makes an object from an array. and index `0` becomes property of the json object. Dont use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make few changes in your code, which will help you achieve your expected output.

> **1.** Use `array_merge` instead of `array_push`
>
> **2.** Set `Errors` key like this `"Errors" => array($error)` instead of `"Errors" => $error`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/784451)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$isSandbox=true;
$message = "Message was sent on 12-31-1999 12:00:00 am";
$errorMsg = "Message bounced back";
$error = array("Code" => 5, "Message" => $errorMsg);
$package = array(
    "Data" => $message,
    "Errors" => array($error)
);
if ($isSandbox)
{
    $sandboxkey = array("Sandboxed" => true);
    $package=array_merge($package, $sandboxkey);
}
echo json_encode($package,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "Data": "Message was sent on 12-31-1999 12:00:00 am",
    "Errors": [
        {
            "Code": 5,
            "Message": "Message bounced back"
        }
    ],
    "Sandboxed": true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! This works perfectly. So, follow up, why `array_merge` instead of `array_push`?

Comment: @user-44651  `array_merge` merges `key` `values` pairs in the specified array where as `array_push` pushes a `array` or a variable at some index.

Answer (score 2):

> *But that adds a "0" then the KVP.*

[`array_push()`](http://php.net/array_push) could be used if the array was a *numeric array* (i.e. the keys were integers - e.g. `0 => 'cat', 1 => 'dog'`. But in this case, the array is an *associative array*. One way to set the desired key, *Sandbox*, is to set the array key by specifying it in bracket notation:

```
if ($isSandbox) {
    $sandboxkey = array( "Sandboxed" => true );
    $package['Sandbox'] = $sandboxkey;
}
```

This is necessary because the other keys of the array are not

See it demonstrated in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/f6bwIKvepWwMlV92).

Otherwise [array_merge()](http://array_merge) could be used:

```
if ($isSandbox) {
    $sandboxArray = array(
    'Sandbox' => array( "Sandboxed" => true )
    );
    $package = array_merge($package, $sandboxArray);
}
```

See a demonstration in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/znFm9dxUM3TddXva).

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5931218/1575353) for more information about numeric vs associative arrays. It is somewhat surprising that the difference isn't explicitly spelled out on the [PHP Array data type page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

> *Additionally, I want the Errors to be listed in an array...*

For this, nest `$error` (an associative-array, which will get converted to a JSON object) in another array.

```
$package = array(
    "Data" => $message,
    "Sandbox" => $sandboxkey,
    "Errors" => array($error)
);
```

Comment: EXCELLENT! Thanks for taking the time to explain `array_push()`

Comment: Yeah NP - I updated the explanation, mentioning array_merge() - perhaps it might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

How to handle json:

- `[]` are arrays in json
- `{}` are objects in json

So to create something like `{'data':[{'depperdata':2}]}` do

```
 $a = new stdClass();
 $a->data = array();
 $b = new stdClass();
 $b->deeperdata=2;
 $a->data[0]=$b;
 print_r(json_encode($a,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

or

```
 $a = array('data'=>array(array('depperdata'=>2)));
 print_r(json_encode($a,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

What does `json_decode`

- if you have an assoc-array it becomes an json_object
- if you have an indexed array it becomes an json_array
- if you have an object it becomes an json_object
- if you have mixed assoc/index array you are getting broken json like your example. property name `0`! (prevent that!)

Have a nice day...

Comment: The `{}` are objects in JS because that is what they are called in php it is an associative array as well.