# Accessing elements into numeric and associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to understand some behavior of PHP with `arrays`. I read the manual and this stck overflow posts :

- [Are numeric and associative arrays in PHP two different things?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931206/are-numeric-and-associative-arrays-in-php-two-different-things)
- [Can items in PHP associative arrays not be accessed numerically (i.e. by index)?
  Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931120/can-items-in-php-associative-arrays-not-be-accessed-numerically-i-e-by-index)

But still some things that is not clear for me.

Look, please, at this code:

```
<?php

  $array = [
    'a',
     3 => 'b',
     1 => 'c',
     'd',
  ];

  var_dump($array[2]); // Null 
  var_dump($array[4]); // string(1) "d"
```

Why PHP assumes that the index of `'d'` is `4` instead of `2`?

**Update**

*If you think that it deserves downvotes, please explain why.* Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are numeric and associative arrays in PHP two different things?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931206/are-numeric-and-associative-arrays-in-php-two-different-things)

Comment: Can someone explain to me why the down votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because if you define an element without an explicit index, PHP will use the highest numeric index of that array plus 1.

In your case, you're defining `3 => 'b'`, so the next array element will have index 4.